# Wait for image to load before proceeding with for loop

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function which I want to loop through a number of div elements. Waiting for each background-image to load before proceeding with the loop.

My current solution is:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("previewImg");
for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){
    var imageSrc = images[i].getAttribute("stylesoon");
    if(imageSrc != "" || imageSrc != null){
        console.log(imageSrc);
        var imgToLoad = new Image();
        imgToLoad.src = "./".imageSrc;
        imgToLoad.onload = function () {
            images[i].style.cssText += "background-image: url('"+imageSrc+"');";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is not waiting for the imgToLoad.onload function to complete before proceeding with the loop. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

All help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not possible with a for loop like that because it is asynchronous. Make a queue and pop off it.

Comment: `imgToLoad.src = "./".imageSrc;` strange looking JavaScript

Comment: So you want to know when they are all done loading..... or do you want to wait for each one to load before doing the next?

Comment: Wait for each to load before doing the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls are asynchronous. So you either need to use async/await with a promise or you need to make a queue and pop off an array.

```js
(function() {
  const elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.previewImg[data-stylesoon]'));

  function loadNext() {
    if (!elems.length) {
      console.log('done');
      return;
    }
    const elem = elems.pop();
    const url = elem.dataset.stylesoon;
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = function() {
      elem.style.backgroundImage = `url('${url}')`;
      loadNext();
    };
    img.onerror = loadNext;
    img.src = url;
  }

  loadNext();
}());
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="previewImg" data-stylesoon="https://placekitten.com/200/200">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="previewImg" data-stylesoon="https://placekitten.com/200/300">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="previewImg" data-stylesoon="https://placekitten.com/200/400">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="previewImg" data-stylesoon="https://placekitten.com/300/500">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - that's perfect. It looks like I need to do some reading into this to fully understand how this works. I really appreciate your help.